# DeprecationWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version warning

Tags: python, pandas

I appending a new row to an existing pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df= df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)
```

This is resulting in the subject DeprecationWarning.

The existing df has a mix of string, float and dateime.date datatypes (8 columns totals).

Is there a way to explicitly specify the columns types in the df.append?

I have looked [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html)  and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) but I still have no solution.   Please advise if there is a better way to append a row to the end of an existing dataframe without triggering this warning.

Comment: You can do `pd.Series(dtype=float64)` instead

Comment: Please share a sample input and expected output.

Comment: `= pd.Series(dtype='float64')` ... with quotes or else error in latest pd here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this

```
Type_new = pd.Series([],dtype=pd.StringDtype())
```

This will create a blank data frame for us.

Answer (score 19):

You can add `dtype` to your code.

`pd.Series(dtype='float64')`

Answer (score 6):

```py
df = df.append(pd.Series(dtype = 'object'), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the accepted solution still results in :

> 'ValueError: No objects to concatenate'

Try this solution from [FutureWarning: on `df['col'].apply(p.Series)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72737997/futurewarning-on-dfcol-applyp-series?noredirect=1&lq=1) :

```
(lambda x: pd.Series(x, dtype="float"))
```