# FutureWarning: on `df['col'].apply(p.Series)`

Tags: pandas

```
 FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
```

while doing

`rc = dataset_ex[column_name].apply(p.Series)`

How one woud avoid warning? What does it mean when one `df.apply(pd.Series)` what's really happening?

Comment: It's `pandas==1.4.2`

Answer (score 8):

This question([DeprecationWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158734/deprecationwarning-the-default-dtype-for-empty-series-will-be-object-instead)) is pretty similar with your question so it'll help you.

You can ignore all python warnings or FutureWarning with the code bellows but it just hides the warning, not solve it.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```

Now, default **dtype of Series** is **float64** but It'll be changed to **object**.

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)  # '1.2.4'
print(pd.Series().dtype)  # dtype('float64') --> dtype('object') in the future
```

If you define dtype of Series, warning will be disappear.

```
rc = dataset_ex[column_name].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, dtype="float"))
```

or

```
rc = dataset_ex[column_name].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, dtype="object"))
```

Comment: Appreciate it! This `rc = dataset_ex[column_name].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, dtype="object"))` did it

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar warning, I solved it by inputting the following code at the top of my code

`n = np.dtype(dtype='int64')`

I hope this helps :)