# pandas how to check if column not empty then apply .str.replace in one line code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

code:

```
df['Rep'] = df['Rep'].str.replace('\\n', ' ')
```

issue:
if the df['Rep'] is empty or null ,there will be an error:

```
Failed: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

is there anyway can handle the situation when the column value is empty or null? If it is empty or null ,just ignore that row

Comment: When you get the error, what does `print (df['Rep'].dtype)` give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the empty series `dtype` will be `float64`.

You can do a workaround using the `astype`:

```
df['Rep'] = df['Rep'].astype('str').str.replace('\\n', ' ')
```

Test code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rep': []})

# works
df['Rep'] = df['Rep'].astype('str').str.replace('\\n', ' ')

# doesn't work
df['Rep'] = df['Rep'].str.replace('\\n', ' ')
```

I don't know which version of pandas you are using by they will changed to `object` the default `dtype`.

Edit: Still won't work with `object`, just tested using the latest version of pandas (2.0.0).

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158734/deprecationwarning-the-default-dtype-for-empty-series-will-be-object-instead)